# Smile timeline widget add custom fields

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add couple of custom fields to the event datasource, something like:

```
{"events":
   [
      {"isDuration": "true",
       "description": "my description
       "color": "#ffcc00",
       "image": "/images/my-img.jpg",
       "link": "http://www.google.co.uk",
       "icon": "/images/red-ico.png",
       "end": null,
       "title": "my title",
       "start": "2012,09,30",
       "textColor": "#777",
       "customField_1": "abc"
       "customField_2" : "def"}
   ]
}
```

then retrieve **customField_1** and **customField_2** in the showBubble event, like so:

```
Timeline.OriginalEventPainter.prototype._showBubble = function(x, y, evt) {

      var cust1 = evt.getCustom1();
      var cust2 = evt.getCustom2();
}
```

Is it possible to add these get methods, and how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simile-widgets/om3EtWzGacQ